# is there something like org-babel for arbitrary major modes?

Tags: org-babel, literate-programming

[org-babel](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html) allows editing source code of arbitrary modes inside an `.org` file.

I'd like to do this (with different syntactic markers) inside my major mode, but `org-babel` is very specific to `org`.

Is there a library that allows one to embed major modes (at least the font-locks) inside a code block in another major mode? Otherwise I guess I need to copy/pasta the relevant parts of `org-babel`.

Comment: Please add some more info - in which way it should behave different from org-babel? What to keep?

Comment: I don't know what to add. I basically want org-babel inside my major mode. e.g. say I have a SQL string embedded in my source code (with some special markers, say `$$$`, not `BEGIN_SRC`), I want to be able to use sql-mode font-locks in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try the following packages:

https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode

https://github.com/polymode/polymode

resp.

https://polymode.github.io/

WRT to literate programming this seems worth to look at too:

https://github.com/alphapapa/outorg